# how to solve solr reload time out exception?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

After execute `zkcli.sh` for updatting my config files, I reload my collection like this:
    http://172.16.30.18:8181/solr/admin/collections?action=RELOAD&name=xin_suggest

but it return an error message:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">500</int>
<int name="QTime">180025</int>
</lst>
<lst name="error">
<str name="msg">reload the collection time out:180s</str>
<str name="trace">
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: reload the collection time out:180s at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleResponse(CollectionsHandler.java:237) at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:168) at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143) at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:660) at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:431) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:227) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:196) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
</str>
<int name="code">500</int>
</lst>
</response>
```

I cannot find any solution to resolve this issuse.

update:

I am not find the reason, but it turned worked when I waiting for about 30 minutes.

Comment: Are you using an EC2 instance? Are you using SolrCloud? If you're have SolrCloud, could you post the topology of your network?

Comment: Do you have a lot of external dependencies like external jars etc. that load with the core?

Comment: I have been using solrcloud. I can access solr admin interface on `8181` port.